# where I need to add "wait.ignoring" to "ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I do not understand the concept of:

```
wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until
 (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("bla bla")));
```

I other words, why do I need to have this part:

```
ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
```

while

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
```

waits till the element is visible so that it is not stale.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions recently that could be understood if you looked at the documentation. Please google your question and spend some time reading before asking basic questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general effect of telling an instance of `FluentWait` (which is what `WebDriverWait` is based on) to ignore exceptions is that if such exception happens when it polls the DOM, it will continue polling rather than let the exception trickle up.

In the specific case of `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` there is no benefit to explicitly ignoring `StaleElementReferenceException` because `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` *already* ignores it. There is an [explicit `try... catch...` block](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/55715c966a32a3f4baeaf8a092ba9c3e6bb80136/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L204) in it that will make it return `null` if the element is stale. I do not know whether older versions of Selenium did not have this `try... catch...` block. Maybe for some earlier versions of Selenium it was necessary to explicitly tell `FluentWait` to ignore this exception.

> waits till the element is visible so that it is not stale.

It is possible for `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` to have to deal with a stale element. It performs its test in two steps:

1. Get a `WebElement` that corresponds to the locator the user passed.
2. Call `.isDisplayed()` on this element.

Between these two steps, it is possible for the DOM to be changed so that the element acquired in the first step is already stale (== no longer *in* the document) by the time the 2nd step runs. It is a very small window of risk, but it exists, and so has to be handled.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words you can understand the above code like this.

```
ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
```

Above ignore is used to ignore an specific exception that may occur while wait is on executing. For example while waiting for an element if a StaleElementReferenceException occures it will ignore the exception and will not throw the exception to the outside.

A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:

1. The element has been deleted entirely.
2. The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

[Stale Element Reference Exception Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)